# Is there a script to manage/search python snippets which understands python code like nullege.com?

Tags: python, search, code-snippets

I have a folder full of python snippets and want to search it in a more intelligent way than grep. Is there already a script which parses python snippets to AST and lets you search it, like http://nullege.com?

For example, if you have the following code:

```
class InspectionFrame(wx.Frame):
    def SaveSettings(self, config):
        w, h = self.GetSize()
```

you should be able to search for wx.Frame.GetSize.

Comment: +1 for pointing out nullege.com

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, ctags is a classic tool for such a task. As of now, python support in exuberant ctags is lacking, but some work have been done last year: http://ctags.sourceforge.net/news.html.
Now indexing of classes, functions, class members, variables and imports are supported.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is awesome, I'd love to see that available.  FFR, this won't do what you want but it's way better than for grep for code searching: [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/), it's "better than grep".